# Error Connecting to Google Datastore outside GAE

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Hi I am trying to connect to Datastore using the below command

DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder().projectId("project-id").authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(new FileInputStream("c:\GoogleCredentials\.json"))).build();

I have created a folder GoogleCredentials in my C: Drive and downloaded the Service account's JSON keyfile into this folder

But I am getting the below error:

Line 38, Column 67: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.String"; candidates are: "com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions$Builder com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions$Builder.projectId(java.lang.String)"

Comment: Isn't it `DatastoreOptions.Builder()...` ? ('B' uppercase)

Comment: no..its lowecase (Uppercase B gives an error)